# Horizontally centering three images on the middle one

Tags: beamer, graphics, horizontal-alignment

Often, in the title page of a beamer presentation, I have to show three logos and some of them are not square images. 
I would like for the middle one to be centered horizontally and the other two to "fill" the rest of the space to the left and to the right, respectively. 
Latex insists in centering the whole group of three images. How can I change this behavior?

```
                  -------------------
--------          |                 |         --------------
|      |          |  this image is  |         |            |
|      |          | centered on the |         |            |
--------          |      slide      |         --------------
                  -------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to hide the widths of the side images:

```
\makebox[\textwidth][s]{% spread out the contents
  \makebox[0pt][l]{<left side image>}%
  \hfill
  <center image>%
  \hfill
  \makebox[0pt][r]{<right side image}%
}
```

If `\centering` is already in effect, you should obtain the same result without the outer `\makebox`, by adding `\\` after the box containing the right side image